# PowerBuilder unit testing framework

Tags: unit-testing, powerbuilder

Is there any ability of PowerBuilder to write and run unit tests? I'm talking about PowerBuilder 12 classic.

Alternatively is there any third party framework or library for unit testing of powerbuilder code?

I'm pretty new to PowerBuilder, so I appreciate any advice or experience on testing PB applications.

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool called PBUnit which may help you.  It is available on Sourceforge [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pbunit/).

You may be interested in [this](http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/1443544) article written by PowerBuilder MVP Yakov Werde in the old PowerBuilder Developer's Journal.  He details the set up and use of this tool.

[Appeon Corporation](https://www.appeon.com/) has taken over the development of PowerBuilder from SAP.  They have mentioned in past presentations on 'future plans' of the expansion of the unit testing capabilities of PB but I don't believe anything specific regarding when this will be done has been stated.

Comment: thanks, pbUnit is exactly what I was looking for. Just the last version  of pbUnit was released 1.5 year ago. Hoping they will continue the development.

Comment: Actually, that project hasn't been updated in 14 years. Only the zip file is new. See my answer for an updated version.

Comment: PDJ link is broken

Comment: Yes PDJ is no longer on line.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [PowerUnit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/powerunit/). It has many enhancements compared to PbUnit.

Comment: I see the last update on PowerUnit in 2014. Do they continue the development? The current PB version is PB 2017.